# bash script for docker permission denied in django project

Tags: django, bash, shell, docker, ubuntu

I am learning `docker` and implemented docker in my Django project, currently, it is working great! no issue at all

Now I am trying to make some command easy to run, that is why I write a shell script.

coz, I am bored writing this too long command:

```
$ docker-compose run web python /code/manage.py migrate --noinput
$ docker-compose run web python /code/manage.py createsuperuser
```

and more like above, to avoid writing long-lined command, i just wrote a shell script and this below:

`manage.sh` is shell script file

```
#!/bin/bash
docker-compose run web python /code/manage.py $1
```

and later I tried to use my `manage.sh` file to `migrate` like

```
$ ./manage.sh migrate
```

But terminal throws me an error that is

```
bash: ./manage.sh: Permission denied
```

I am not getting actually what's wrong with it even I tried with `sudo`

if i try with `sudo`, like `sudo ./docker-manage.sh migrate`

it throws me this error: `sudo: ./docker-manage.sh: command not found`

I believe if you are a docker expert, you can solve my problem. can you please help me in this case?

Comment: Use with sudo ./manage.sh migrate

Comment: Is the script file executable?  (Does `chmod +x manage.sh` help?)

Comment: I already tried with sudo, but no luck, read the post carefully

Comment: yes, it helps chmod +x manage.sh

Comment: It solved my problem but every time running chmod +x manage.sh this command is boring, anyother solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you want to set up your containers and images so that they can run completely autonomously.  Having to repeatedly run `docker-compose run ...` like this suggests you should be moving more work into your container's startup.

Docker containers have two parts to specify what single program the container runs, an *entrypoint* and a *command*.  If you specify both, the command is passed as command-line arguments to the entrypoint.  A very typical pattern is to use a shell script as an entrypoint that first does whatever setup is required, and then runs the command as its last action.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# I am /docker-entrypoint.sh

# Run migrations &c.
python /code/manage.py migrate --noinput
python /code/manage.py createsuperuser

# Run the main container process (our script's arguments)
exec "$@"
```

Then in your `Dockerfile`, specify this script as the `ENTRYPOINT`, and whatever it is you want your container to actually do as the `CMD`.

```sh
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Assume this copies docker-entrypoint.sh too, and that
# it's marked executable in your local filesystem
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

# IMPORTANT: use JSON-array syntax for ENTRYPOINT
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# This is the main thing your container does
# (It could use plain-string syntax if you want)
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

(If you've currently split the default command between `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, move it all into `CMD`.)

One thing you can do with this is get a debugging shell.  The entrypoint always runs unless you specifically override it, but you can separately specify the command.  So if you want to look at what your migrations do in isolation you can

```
sudo docker-compose run web bash
```

`bash` will get passed as a parameter to the entrypoint script, which will then run migrations and then drop you into a shell.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the script is not executable.

What you should do to fix this is:

```
chmod u+x ./manage.sh
./manage.sh migrate
```

Example when executable permissions are not set:

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:newfol myuser$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser  staff  0 13 Sep 13:53 manage.sh
Users-MacBook-Pro:newfol myuser$ ./manage.sh
-bash: ./manage.sh: Permission denied
Users-MacBook-Pro:newfol myuser$ chmod u+x manage.sh
Users-MacBook-Pro:newfol myuser$ ./manage.sh
it works
```